# Verificar se numero é inteiro no Access

Tags: microsoft-access, vba

Como verificar se um número é inteiro no VBA do Access?

Eu tentei

```vb
If Int(Me.Numero) Then
    Msgbox "É inteiro"
End If
```

Mas não funcionou.

Eu queria que se eu digitasse 8,5 ele retornasse "Não é inteiro".

O campo é Não Acoplado.

Comment: Descreva melhor o que é 'não funcionou', erro? resultado não esperado?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A função `int( )` retorna a parte inteira do número. Por exemplo,

```vba
intNumber = Int(902.3)
```

faria com que a variável intNumber fosse igual a 902.

No seu caso, basta testar se o número é igual ao inteiro dele. Ou seja:

```vba
If Me.Numero = Int(Me.Numero) Then
    blablabla
Else
    bla2bla2bla2
End If
```

Comment: Porque não pensei nisso antes, valeu pessoal.

Answer (score 1):

Segundo esse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992922/how-do-i-express-the-term-if-x-is-integer-in-vba-language), para checar se o tipo da variavel é int/integer, use esse código

```vba
If TypeName(x) = "Integer" Then
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a expressão abaixo, a função `val` retorna apenas a parte inteira do número, aí basta comparar o número usando a função contra ele mesmo:

```
if val([valor]) = [valor] then 
    msgbox "Inteiro"
else

end if
```